# Phone is mising in the acoustic model

Tags: cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

When I use `pocketsphinx_continuous -infile my audio -dict my_dictionary -jsgf my_jsgf`

I got these errors:

> ERROR: "dict.c", line 195: Line 1: Phone 'I' is mising in the acoustic model; word 'Bismi' ignored
>
> ERROR: "dict.c", line 195: Line 2: Phone 'I' is mising in the acoustic model; word 'Bismi(2)' ignored
>
> ERROR: "dict.c", line 195: Line 3: Phone 'A' is mising in the acoustic model; word 'Lahi' ignored
>
> ERROR: "dict.c", line 195: Line 4: Phone 'A' is mising in the acoustic model; word 'Lahi(2)' ignored
>
> ERROR: "dict.c", line 195: Line 5: Phone 'HI' is mising in the acoustic model; word 'Rahmani' ignored
>
> ERROR: "dict.c", line 195: Line 6: Phone 'HI' is mising in the acoustic model; w
>
> ERROR: "fsg_search.c", line 141: The word 'wa' is missing in the dictionary

But, I got the a good accuracy when I tested my data in the result file

> TOTAL Words: 420 Correct: 420 Errors: 0
>
> TOTAL Percent correct = 100.00% Error = 0.00% Accuracy = 100.00%
>
> TOTAL Insertions: 0 Deletions: 0 Substitutions: 0

How can i solve theses problems?
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the dictionary to match the acoustic model phoneset or use the acoustic model to match your dictionary. Acoustic model is configured with `-hmm` option.

Comment: i used -hmm option i didn't get the text i got these  INFO: continuous.c(305): pocketsphinx_continuous COMPILED ON: Mar  8 2016, AT: 23:45:54

INFO: cmn_prior.c(131): cmn_prior_update: from <  8.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 >
INFO: cmn_prior.c(149): cmn_prior_update: to   < 57.55 15.24 -2.83  2.28 -13.93 -4.90 16.14 -10.01 18.20 -2.65 10.41  1.24 10.51 >
INFO: fsg_search.c(843): 310 frames, 2347 HMMs (7/fr), 6071 senones (19/fr), 926 history entries (2/fr) How can i solve this problem?Thank you

Comment: To see just the text you can add an option to disable logs: `-logfn /dev/null`

Comment: i got nothing . what could be my mistake ? hasan@hasan-SVE14112EGW:~/Desktop/as/sphinxtrain$ pocketsphinx_continuous -infile '/home/hasan/Desktop/as/sphinxtrain/an4/wav/an4test_clstk/td/an1-td-b.wav' -hmm '/home/hasan/Desktop/as/sphinxtrain/model_parameters' -dict '/home/hasan/Desktop/as/sphinxtrain/etc/an4.dic' -jsgf '/home/hasan/Desktop/as/sphinxtrain/etc/an4.jsgf' -logfn /dev/null

Comment: There is no mistake, nothing is also a result. Probably your audio is too short, try longer audio. To recognize short audio add a line `-cmninit 57,15,-2` to model feat.params file

Comment: Thank you so much .You help me a lot .Thank you my lecture